# Flutter ios appstore validateReceipt on non-consumable in-app purchase

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, receipt-validation

I seem to be stuck on this. Trying to validate the receipt (server side) on an in-app purchase on IOS (haven't tried with android, yet.)

I'm using the official `in_app_purchase` pub package.

This is the setup to initialize the purchase:

```dart
   Future<bool> initiatePurchase() async {
       ...
       (verify store is available)
       ..
    print ("==> Store available, initiating purchase");

    final PurchaseParam purchaseParam =
        PurchaseParam(productDetails: _productDetails![0]);

    await InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);

    return true;
  }
```

Here's my verify purchase call:

```dart
  Future<bool> _verifyPurchase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    PurchaseVerifRest purchaseRest = PurchaseVerifRest();
    Map<String,dynamic> rsp = await purchaseRest.verifyPurchase(
      {
        "source": purchaseDetails.verificationData.source,
        "vfdata": purchaseDetails.verificationData.serverVerificationData
      });
    // bundle up the source and verificationData in a map and send to rest
    // call

      
    return rsp['status'] == 200;
  }
```

On the server side, the code looks like this (NodeJS/express app)

```js
  // (in router.post() call - 'purchaseData' is the map sent in the above code,
  //                           the 'vfdata' member is the 'serverVerificationData'
  //.                          in the 'purchaseDetails' object)

  if (purchaseData.source == ('app_store')) {
    const IOS_SHARED_SECRET = process.env...;
    let postData = {
      'receipt-data': purchaseData['vfdata'],
      'password': IOS_SHARED_SECRET
    };

    try {
      let verif_rsp = await execPost(postData);
      retStatus = verif_rsp.statusCode;
      msg = verif_rsp.data;
    } catch (e) {
      retStatus = e.statusCode;
    }
  }
```

What I get back, invariably is

```
  210003 - Receipt could not be authenticated
```

... even though the purchase seems to go through, whether I validate or not.

Details/questions:

- Testing with a sandbox account.
- This is for a 'non-consumable' product purchase.
- I'm assuming that `purchaseDetails.verificationData.serverVerificationData` is the payload containing the receipt to send to Apple for verification.  Is this not correct?  Is there another step I need to do to get the receipt data?
- I've read in other posts that the verification step is only for recurring subscriptions and not for other types of products.  Is this correct?  I don't see anything in Apple's docs to indicate this.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Update - in the original post I realized I didn't preface the 'InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable()' call with an 'await'.  I've updated that in the app and here and tried again - no changes, seems to work pretty much the same way.

Comment: Not getting any input.  I guess what I'll do is ignore the verification step on IOS for non-consumable purchases and move on.  See what android does...